# borders in tkinter not getting displayed

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am writing a small program in python to get a grid like effect wherin each grid is a label.

below is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.configure(bg='black')

FRAME = Frame( bg='red')
FRAME.pack()

heading=["source","name","code","identity","source","name","code","identity"]
r1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
r=0
c=0
for k in range(0,5):
    for i in  heading:
        lab = Label (FRAME,text = i,bg='cyan',padx='3.0m', pady='3.0m')

        lab.grid(row=r,column=c)
        c = c+1
    r=r+1
    c=0

root.mainloop()
```

I cannot get the border of labels set. Please specify which attribute I should incorporate, I've tried using border width without success.

Answer (score 2):

You say you can't get the border of the labels to be set, but I don't see anywhere in your code where you've defined a border for the labels.

If you want borders on the actual label widgets, use the `borderwidth` and `relief` options:

```
lab = Label (..., borderwidth=1, relief="solid"
```

If, instead of a border on the widget, you want a space *between* each widget so that the background shows through, use the `padx` and `pady` options when you use `grid`:

```
lab.grid(..., padx=1, pady=1)
```